# Compare values in list of Json - Presto

Tags: sql, presto, dbt

How to check using Presto that end_date > start_date in every Json of the list. Time in epoch milliseconds. All there lists are in a column  name 'dates'

```
[{end_date=1662960600000, start_date=1662984000000}, {end_date=1663047000000, start_date=1663045200000}, {end_date=1663133400000, start_date=1663131600000}]
```

Comment: That is not json though. What is the return of `select typeof(dates)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on provided output your data looks like array of maps or rows, so you can handle it accordingly with [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html):

```sql
-- sample data
with test_data (dates) AS (
    VALUES (array[
        map(array['end_date','start_date'], array[1662960600000, 1662984000000])
        , map(array['end_date','start_date'], array[1662984000000, 1662960600000])])
)

-- query
select all_match(dates, m -> m['end_date'] > m['start_date']) all_start_earlier_then_end
from test_data;
```

Output:

| all_start_earlier_then_end |
| --- |
| false |

rows version will look like:

```sql
select all_match(dates, m -> m.end_date > m.start_date) all_start_earlier_then_end
from test_data;
```

If `all_match` is not available (due to older version) you can workaround with `filter` and `cardinality`:

```sql
select cardinality(filter(dates, m -> m.end_date < m.start_date)) = 0 all_start_earlier_then_end
from test_data;
```